# Facebook "Like" button versus Facebook login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I've been using the code here to handle Facebook logins:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#example

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

I recently added the Like button but it appears that there is a separate flow for handling the login information that allows likes versus regular logins.  Normally, when I log out, FB details (e.g., friends) can't be retrieved until another Facebook login is established.  However, with the Like button, even if I logout and log back in or even log in with a different username, the Like button still works and is tied to the original FB user.  To make that more clear, here's what happens:

Session 1 (FB user):  FB like button is clicked --> FB login dialog pops up, info is entered, and like shows up on Facebook --> Log out

Session 2 (Other user):  If the button still shows that the page is liked, clicking it again shows that the first user no longer likes the page on the actual Facebook page.  Clicking it again to like the page again shows the first user liking the page again.

I'd like to tie the Like button login information to the regular SDK login.  I'm reading that there is a lot of security around the Like and Share buttons so I'm wondering if that's even possible.

Comment: There is nothing to “tie” here. The Like button requires the user to be logged in to Facebook, nothing more. And your logout likely did log the user out of your app only, not out of Facebook as well.

Comment: I see, so this is handled at the level of the browser, not individual pages?  It's probably not an issue that will cause a ton of problems in practice but still worth checking.